# "Failed to start Load Kernel modules" error is thrown

Tags: 18.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

**I use ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA and Intel Graphics Cards**. This problem had **interrupted boot** first on 10th December. I tried updating my NVIDIA graphics drivers but it came with broken packages. I somehow fixed it using the tty and linux seemed to work fine since then. Today I switched to my Intel GPU for power saving as I was using my laptop's battery but the problem reappeared after restarting. I again somehow fixed it by running

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and booted into the GUI successfully and installed the required Graphics Drivers. Then I ran `journalctl` as suggested by many forums and found out that this same error had occurred since **22nd October** but went unnoticed. I thought that it was a kernel panic and updated the kernel to 5.4 by running `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04`  but after restart, and **successful boot**, still the same error message could be found in logs.

**The system is fully usable and working but is still throwing this error every time I restart.**

Is there anything to be scared about this or should I just ignore it. Can this problem cause potential damage like the entire OS crashing and corrupting all mount drives and devices. Pls help. Thanks.